# Captive network with MacOS and Facebook cookies issue

Tags: facebook, macos, cookies, captivenetwork

When using Facebook Login from a **Captive Portal on MAC OS** (Tested on versions: 10.10.5/2), we get an error with "**cookies required**".
On Safari on the same mac works ok. As an UserAgent example: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) On other sites of our captive portal we get to work on cookies but reading from Server side, on javascript cookie reading we get that error.

There could be workaround for this? On previous weeks ago we do not have any problem with facebook login on MAC OS captive portals.

Thanks.

Comment: please provide as a "code snippet" how you are doing what you explained in your question, would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose try to do the following:

Capture the HTTP Request Headers before / after login in a non functioning and a functioning version of MacOS.

Probably cookie header is corrupted / security headers added / etc.